# Proof verification: $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac{b}{a+b}$ cannot be both real.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, complex-numbers

I want to prove that $a$ and $b$ that satisfy

$\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac{b}{a+b}$

cannot both be real. Is the following argument correct:

$\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac{b}{a+b} \quad \leftrightarrow \quad (a+b)^2=ab \quad \leftrightarrow \quad a^2+b^2=-ab $

Let's assume that both $a$ and $b$ are real. Then, in any case, $a^2+b^2$ is positive. Yet for the right side of the equation to be positive, $ab$ must be negative, so $a$ and $b$ have different signs.

We also have the following:

$(a+b)^2 = ab \quad \leftrightarrow \quad a+b = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$

As either $a$ or $b$ is negative, but not both, either $\sqrt{a}$ or $\sqrt{b}$ is imaginary, but not both. So, $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is a complex number. This, in turn, means that either $a$ or $b$ must contribute the imaginary part of the complex number $a+b$. Hence, we have a contradiction, and thus it is not possible for $a$ and $b$ to both be real.

I don't trust myself when it comes to proofs, so I'm looking for reassurance that this is correct or constructive feedback if there is a mistake. Thanks! (:

Comment: Your equivalence is not true. $(a+b)^2=ab$ has solutions, where both $a$ and $b$ are real.

Comment: It should be enough to conclude from: $\sqrt{x}$ for $x < 0$ does not have real solutions. And additionally possibly that a product of reals is a real.

Comment: Given that $a\neq 0$ from the original equation($a$ is in the denominator of the LHS), you could divide both side of $a^2+ab+b^2=0$ by $a^2$ and argue that $t^2+t+1=0$ does not have any real solution.

Comment: 3 comments and I'm already lost (; 1. which equivalence is not true....? I thought the rearrangements were completely basic. Can you pinpoint the mistake? also, I'm quite sure that the original equation has no solutions where both $a$ and $b$ are real (it's an example from a book) 2. I'm not sure how your comment connects to my post exactly, sorry. 3. it's also possible to use the quadratic formula to find $a$ in terms of $b$, which also leads to a proof. but I'm curious if the one that I posted is OK.

Comment: Somewhere you need to assert that $a,b$ are not zero.

Comment: No reason to be lost! It is very easy: $\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac{b}{a+b}$ cannot have a solution with both $a$ and $b$ real, but $(a+b)^2=-ab$ can. How could they then ever be equivalent equations? You have used $\leftrightarrow$ there - this is not correct (and you were asking for constructive feedback if there is a mistake).

Comment: you're simply asserting that $(a+b)^2=-ab$ has solutions where $a$ and $b$ are both real, which is a statement of about the level of complexity that I'm trying to prove. so, I don't want to presuppose it. also, I thought they were equivalent as I get from one to the other using (what I thought were) simple equivalence transformations (simple multiplication). not saying you're wrong, just trying to explain why your response isn't resonating! but thanks for engaging (:

Comment: If $t= b/a$, then $t^2+t+1=0 $ supplies two complex roots among three cube roots of unity.

Comment: @ichbinviele Certainly Dietrich Burde means that if $a=b=0$, then $(a+b)^2=ab$, but the original equation is meaningless, as it would have divisions by $0$.

Comment: aah, thank you. yes, now it's all coming together. (: I thought I didn't even have to mention that $a\neq0$, as it's so obvious, but now I see one more reason why I should have mentioned it after all. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is right, just keep it simple. Suppose $a , b \in \mathbb{R}$, then  $(a+b)^{2}=ab$ implies $ab\geqslant0$. On the other hand, $a^{2}+b^{2}=-ab$ implies $ab\leqslant0$. So, both the conditions implies $ab=0$. Now, $a\neq0$, so $b=0$ forces $a+b=0$, a contradiction. Therefore, $a,b$ cannot be both real.

Comment: thanks, this is great. uses the same observations that I use, yet is more elegant, or no? is my proof at some point *mistaken*, though? also, some of the comments on my original post are confusing to me, it'd be awesome if you could help dispel some of that confusion! <3

Answer (score 4):

If $t= b/a$, then simplifying we have a quadratic $t^2+t+1=0 $ supplying two complex roots (among three cube roots of unity).

Since $t= b/a$,  if $a$ real then $b$ has to be complex,
and.
if $b$ real then $a$ has to be  complex. As you say, both cannot be real at the same time, $ a+b $ is always complex.

Comment: I knew of this way of proving the statement, but it doesn't really connect to my way of proving it. hence I chose the other answer as the correct response. still, many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

> $\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac{b}{a+b} \quad \leftrightarrow \quad (a+b)^2=ab \quad \leftrightarrow \quad a^2+b^2=-ab$

Rearranging and multiplying by $\,(a-b)\,$:

$$
0 = a^2+ab+b^2 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) = a^3 - b^3
$$

If $a,b$ are real numbers, $a^3=b^3 \implies a=b$, but the original equality is either undefined if $a=b=0$ or otherwise false if $a=b\ne0$, so no real solutions exist.

Answer (score 0):

Without using algebraic *expansion* .

---

Let

$$
\frac{a+b}{a}=\frac {b}{a+b}=k
$$

Since $\thinspace ab=0$ leads to a contradiction, then you have $ab≠0$ and observing that $a+b$ and $\dfrac {1}{a+b}$ have the *same* sign, this implies that $\dfrac 1a$ and $b$ can *not* have opposite signs. This follows $\dfrac ba>0$, which means $k=1+\dfrac ba>0\thinspace .$

Terefore, you have :

$$
\begin{align}0<k&=\frac {a+b-b}{a-a-b}=-\frac ab<0\end{align}
$$

A contradiction .

---

Regarding the method you apply, you can also finish your solution by *completing the square* :

$$
\begin{align}a^2+ab+b^2&=\left(b+\frac a2\right)^2+\frac {3a^2}{4}\\
&>0,\thinspace \forall a≠0\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$b=xa\Rightarrow\\\frac{a+xa}{a}=\frac{xa}{a+xa}\Rightarrow
\\\frac{a(1+x)}{a}=\frac
{xa}{a(1+x)}\Rightarrow\\1+x=\frac{x}{1+x}\Rightarrow\\(1+x)^2=x\Rightarrow\\x^2+x+1=0$$

But this equation has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$.